Should num_pools in urllib3.PoolManager be bigger than max_workers in ThreadPoolExecutor?
I am using ThreadPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures to run multiple HTTP requests concurrently. I’m wondering if the number of threads specified in max_workers affects the optimal number of connection pools in urllib3.PoolManager. Specifically, should the number of connection pools ideally be greater than the number of threads to optimize request caching?

Wild guess, but I'd think the opposite. Assuming the thread does work outside of a request, that's time where another thread could get the connection and start its work. But that also depends on what "optimize" means. This assumes there is an advantage to keeping the number of connections down (like, not angering the server).
